# ViewFlipper Switch in Android Studio Graphical Interface?

Tags: xml, eclipse, layout, android-studio, viewflipper

Thanks for taking a second and responding to my question if you get the time; I'm fairly new to programming android so any help is great!

I am using Android Studio, and have written an XML layout with multiple layouts in it that I switch between using ViewFlipper.showNext() or ViewFlipper.setDisplayedChild().  Programmatically, everything is working excellent.  However, I am using the graphical XML interface of Android Studio and would like to be able to see the layout displayed by showNext() in the graphical interface.

Does anyone know how to manually flip the viewFlipper in the Android Studio graphical interface (or in Eclipse for that matter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I see is putting the right code part as the first child of the viewflipper to see rendering in the graphical layout.

Comment: Yeah I haven't found a way either in Android Studio or Eclipse.  In the end, though it didn't matter because I've switched to using more intents instead.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is drag the views that you don't want as the first to the viewflipper. This places/stacks those views underneath the view that you want.

-ViewFlipper
   -ViewUwant
   -viewuduntwant